# No valid “aps-environment while using FirebasePushNotificationPlugin in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Getting this on iOS , while using FirebasePushNotificationPlugin -- {no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application}. 
Does anybody know what may have been causing this?

I have followed all the steps described here https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin

Comment: Have you enabled push notification feature in app id in developer portal?

Comment: @George my signing certificate was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In Entitlements.plist add this key  aps-environment with value development for development mode or production for production mode

```
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
    ...
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

The certificate on the firebase console and Visual Studio were mismatching.